# BLE pairing failure when changing MAC address using HCI command

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I'm engaging in dev. project which uses BlueZ v5.26 and TI CC2564 chip.

Recently there needs to change BT MAC address to be in the range of that customer owns. To meet, I used hci command as chip maker guides in the following link. And, I also tried with 'bdaddr' tool in bluez.

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC256x_VS_HCI_Commands#HCI_VS_Write_BD_Addr_.280xFC06.29

It looks controller MAC address is changed, but Bluetooth daemon still keeps chip original MAC address. Bluetoothctl shows original address. When trying to pair with BLE device, authentication failure happens at the moment. I guess it's because of this address mismatch in the daemon. Is there any way to make bluetooth daemon to use revised address after updating MAC with HCi command?

Thank you for the answer in advance.

Comment: Which address is advertised by the chip? Does the remote device see the changed address or the original address?

Comment: After changing the BD address, have you tried hciconfig hcix reset

Comment: At the moment, no sniffer device I have such that I don't have idea which address is advertised. But I guess changed one is used.

Comment: Preeti, when I call "hciconfig -i hci0 reset", address is reverted as original value. So it's not the solution to make bluez stack to be reset with the changed address.